# Setting C# SemaphoreSlim minimum count does not seem to work

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, semaphore

Here is my code

```
   SemaphoreSlim slim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            _ = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(2000);
                _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Unleash!");
                slim.Release();
            });
            _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Waiting");
            await slim.WaitAsync();
            _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Done");
```

The output is ironically as follows:

```
Waiting
Unleash!
Done
```

AFAIK WaitAsync() is suppose to allow the thread since I've set initial count as 1. Somehow it's not behaving that way

Any help?

Comment: Instead of `_testOutputHelper.WriteLine` => `Console.WriteLine`, so that your example can be compiled and tested by everyone.

Comment: Was running in a unit test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to `await` your `Task.Delay(2000)`, so this line basically does nothing and `Task.Run` thread immediately goes and writes "Unleash!", then releases semaphore. So to achieve what you want, just await that delay, giving main thread time to reach `WaitAsync` first:

```
SemaphoreSlim slim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
_ = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Unleash!");
    slim.Release();
});
Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
await slim.WaitAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Comment: Oh silly me! Thanks